# Multiple pop in one line

Tags: arrays, perl, syntax, arguments

I found a line of Perl code which uses `pop` in a way that I've never seen before. I always thought that `pop` returns exactly one item from an array, but the following usage does differently:

```
my ($self, $loop, $resources) = @{pop @_};
```

It seems that the programmer is using one line of code, and one `pop` command, to grab three items from the argument array, without creating an explicit `for` loop. How exactly does this work?

Comment: If you did want "multiple pops" in one line, you'd use `splice`, e.g. `my ($x,$z,$z) = splice(@_, -3);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this example **@_** is an array, and the last element is expected to be an arrayref.

So, `pop(@_)` gets the last element from **@_** and then it is dereferenced into an array; saving first 3 elements into $self, $loop, and $resources.

This can be rewritten like this:

```
my $self = $_[-1]->[0];
my $loop = $_[-1]->[1];
my $resources = $_[-1]->[2];
```

Or like this:

```
my $temp = pop @_;
my ($self, $loop, $resources) = @$temp;
```

So, actually it is not "Multiple pop in one line"